# Why does my mysql query takes way too long to produce results

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i wrote the following code to retrieve data from a database, but its too slow on its execution, can anybody have a look on it and give a few optimizing tips for better performance.

what really happens is im creating a new table by binding existing current data from few other tables.

```
$table_count = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'datamatrix' 
AND table_name 
LIKE 'tracking_%' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count)){

$trackingtable = $row["TABLE_NAME"];

$update = mysql_query("SELECT id as unp FROM $trackingtable");
$col = mysql_fetch_assoc($update);
$col_id = ($col["unp"]);

$var1 = mysql_query("SELECT useragent as ua 
FROM trackpanel 
WHERE id = $col_id");
$col_ua = ($var1["ua"]);
$browser = get_browser($col_ua, true);


$new_timestamp = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMP FROM $trackingtable 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP 
DESC LIMIT 1");
        $col_new = mysql_fetch_assoc($new_timestamp);

$new_timestamp1 = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMP FROM $trackingtable 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP 
ASC LIMIT 1");
$col_old = mysql_fetch_assoc($new_timestamp1);

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO report (`trackingID`,`trackname`,`accountname`,`accountID`, `status`, `clickcount`, `earliest_click`,`recent_click`,`platform`,`device`,`browser`,`browser_version`)
SELECT b.trackingID, `trackname`, accountname, c.accountID, status, total_clicks,'".$col_new['TIMESTAMP']."','".$col_old['TIMESTAMP']."','".$browser['platform']."','".$browser['device_name']."','".$browser['browser']."','".$browser['version']."'
FROM $trackingtable a, datamat b, trackaccounts c
WHERE a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 YEAR) AND a.trackingID = b.trackingID AND b.accountID = c.accountID") 
or die(mysql_error());
} 

?>
```

Comment: Please learn to indent your code.

Comment: ok sorry i will do it now

Comment: ...and to not use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: how many records in `information_schema.tables`?

Comment: ***Another suggestion: DO NOT use the `mysql` API as it is deprecated, instead use MySQLi. You are likely to get responses on this question referencing the same thing.***

Comment: Hey, Please learn PDO or MySQLi

Comment: It may not make any difference but depending on how big the table is, you might be better off doing this `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 YEAR)` in PHP. Also, you can use microtime(time) to see which parts of your code take the longest.

Comment: BTW, this kind of solution is often indicative of poor design. I think that, in general, distributed code should never need to access the information schema!

Comment: I ***did*** say about most users commenting about you using `MySQL` instead of `MySQLi`: http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEBE0viSfbio98mjtvl46g8kWm1GawWjHDlRHDhg6UNMXZqJzR

Comment: Mysqli might be more up to date but it is not going to write decent sql for you, neither put the right index where needed.

Comment: @Strawberry Agreed. Most webhosts give you access to `information.schema` along with any other website databases you have; perhaps the OP is trying to get around shelling out for another MySQL database by using the `information.schema`, ***not that the webhost should be allowing them to freely modify it.***

Comment: thanku all for your comments..ill go through your tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how your database is set up and indexed, and what table storage engines you are using, I can only guess as to why its slow.

1. Your first query could return multiple rows consisting of table names
2. You run 4 simple select statements.
3. You run an insert with a select statement. The select query here also joins 3 tables together

The second and third parts of the list are run for each row which gets looped from the first query. If your tables are InnoDB, the selects will be slower whereas the insert is faster. Opposite is true for MyISAM.

Each query has its own latency because it queries the database separately. You would be better off combining the 1st, 3rd and 4th queries in the while loop as they query the same table.

The insert and select query I guess will most probably be the slowest since it joins 3 tables. That select query can definitely be optimised.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why your queries may be slow is because of a lack on index on your trackingtable, even if you didn't specify which query was slow.

Check for a index presence on

- column id on table trackpanel
- columns timestamp and trackingID on table trackingtable,
- columns trackingID and accountId on table datamat,
- column accountId on table trackaccounts

Comment: Definitely not the only reason. The last select with the 3 table join is a lazy join which can be cleaned up alot.

Comment: That's the main if not only reason.

Comment: @DavidDoumèche That may *not* be the only reason. The connection could be slow, the database server could have insufficient resources, e.t.c.

Comment: Or the table type may be inapropriate, etc... But he didn't reported a performance issue on the remaining query

Comment: thanku all for your comments..ill go through your tips